# Display welcome/startup/splash screen

Tags: emacs

I know how to disable the welcome / splash / startup screen in Emacs. How can this screen be (re)displayed at a later time?

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd> shows the "About GNU Emacs" screen, which is not the same as the "GNU Emacs" (welcome) screen.

Welcome screen:
[image: Emacs Welcome screen]

About screen:
[image: Emacs About screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: use `(display-splash-screen)`.

More pedantically, try using `apropos` to noodle around to find the relevant function: `M-x apropos RET splash` will give you a shortish list of functions and variables relating to the splash screen -- it won't take too much trial and error to find the right items.

Comment: The short version solved my problem. Thanks!